# Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object in

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I got the error showing above. I have looked on this website, but I can't find the right fix to solve my problem.

I am trying to write a User-*class*. The following code is my code so far.

```
class User
{

    private $_id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        global $db;

        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $this->_id);

        $query->execute();

    }

}
```

The result is the following error and I don't know how to fix this...

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object in

**Edit:**

Here is how I am using it:

```
$user = new User($_SESSION['logged_in']); 
$username = $user->getUsername();
```

Sidenote: `session_start();` is loaded.

Comment: How are you using this?

Comment: $user = new User($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        $username = $user->getUsername();

Comment: Oh, yet another lovely `global $db;`.

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: Yeah it is @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Lycaon See Meda's answer below if you haven't tried it/seen it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using global variable is really a poor approach.

Read this blog entry:

**[Global Variables Are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)**

It explains why it is not a good idea.

If the `$db` is null, most likely prepare will not return  the statement object.

Then `$query` will not be a statemnt, therefore `bindValue` wont be recognize.

Instead pass the connection to your class, and just stop using globals.

And also your function was not returning any data, I modify it to return the username.

```
class User
{

    private $_id;
    private $db;

    public function __construct($id, $conn)
    {
        $this->_id = $id;
        $this->$db = $conn;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $this->_id);

        $query->execute();
        $data = $query->fetch();

        return $data['username'];

    }

}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['logged_in'];
$conn = new PDO('xxx');
$user = new User($id, $conn); 
$username = $user->getUsername();
```

Answer (score -1):

It seams to me that your query object is `$db` not `$query`... if so, then it's normal that the $query is missing `bindValue()`, because it's not an object, therefor it does not have any methods.

try to use `$db->bindValue()` and let us know how it went :D

Comment: I am defining $query above.

Comment: ok, then... I missed that, sorry :D var_dump $query before bindValue() to check if it is an object. If not, the db object was not created.